# Play in the suntour front suspension of my raleigh hybrid bike, what exactly is the problem? can i repair on my own?

Tags: maintenance, repair, fork, suspension, hybrid-bike

I have a Raleigh Misceo 700c bike, and recently I can feel some play in the front suspension. At first I thought it was from the headset, so I did some adjustment by tightening the screw on the top area of headset but the problem is still there. After keen observation I came to know that there is some movement in the suspension area. Bottom legs are giving slight movement against the top one which create slight play while applying front brake and also while crossing over a bump. So what exactly is the problem? can I repair it on my own?

Yes, the play is front and back. And it is at the point where upper and lower legs meet. Suspension is Suntour nex sf14

Comment: is the play front to back or side to side, and how sure are you that the play is indeed where the upper and lower legs of the fork meet? The top screw of the head set could just be an expander bolt or the nut to the star nut, which if you have a blown bearing wouldn't help much.

Comment: And if you didn't loosen your pinch bolts(if it's a threadless headset system), adjusting that top bolt won't actually adjust anything...

Comment: I believe those are quite low-end Suntour forks so it is not inconceivable that they have developed some play between the uppers and lowers.

Answer (score 2):

A play of the inner (upper) legs inside the outer (lower) legs is typical for cheap suspensions.

Repairs would mean exchange of the outer legs (if you can find the parts, which is rare for this pricepoint), but it is not uncommon for these entry level parts to come with some play already from the factory as my local retailer assured me when I complained about it. I asked for a replacement and they said I could get an even worse one.

If it bothers you I recommend an upgrade, if you are just concerned, I'd say ride it till it gets unusable. Remember, bike shops sell them like that, and many customers never see an issue.

Suntour offers many of the current entry-level forks and some argue you'd be better off with a stiff fork instead.

If you want to upgrade a-la-cheap, a used Rockshox, Fox or Manitou suspension fork would work fine (I would just stay clear of very old ones, as they are not service-able anymore due to lack of service parts). With some patience you can find them in 700c size.

Comment: Thanks brett for the info. Is there any way i can replace this suspension fork with rigid fork??

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with your particular frame. I think this deserves  it's own question.